# Extjs POST requires shows "403error"

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-applications, extjs4

I face 403 error, when application going POST require:

```
//some controller code
         {text: 'save',
          ui: 'confirm',
          scope: this,
          handler: function() {
              Ext.Ajax.request({
              url:'/api/renter/',
              method:'POST',
              params: {
                  
                "document": "",
                "document_num": "",
                "legal_type": "",
                "_represent": "",
                "position_represent": "",
                "certificate": ""
                    
              },
              jsonData:{
                   ReplaceAllRefs: true
              }
          })
      }
```

When I click on 'save' button POST request don't has done successful. In Chrome browser debug I see:

```
ext-modern-all-debug.js:15778 POST http://localhost:8001/api/renter/?document=&document_num=&legal_type=&_represent=&position_represent=&certificate= 403 (Forbidden)
```

What th wrong? How it is solve?

Comment: Does that API need any kind of authentication?

Comment: Yes, for database. But login and parol have defined in manage.py file. You think it is problem of authentification?